# De Rham cohomology of a matrix lie group.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

In many smooth manifold texts, De Rham cohomology of on smooth manifold is introduced. There are many examples. However, I can't find computational results of the matrix lie group, for example, $O(n,1), SO(n), SU(n)$.

How can I compute De rham cohomology of them?